# "./cosmomc: Relink" `/intel/xlibirc.so' with `/lib/libc.so.6' for IFUNC symbol `memmove' Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: linux

Recently, I tried to install CosmoMC in my Linux, and I followed some tutorials, e.g., https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1354.pdf, but after installing all the required software, I just ran the code with:

```
cd CosmoMC
make all
./cosmomc test.ini
```

but the error raised:
"./cosmomc: Relink" `/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.7.259/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libirc.so' with`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6' for IFUNC symbol `memmove' Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem via reconfiguring the plc-3.01

```
tar -xf COM_Likelihood_Code-v3.0_R3.01.tar.gz
cd plc-3.01
./waf configure --lapack_mkl=${MKLROOT} --install_all_deps --cfitsio_prefix=/path_of_your_cfitsio
# edit environment variable
vi ~/.bashrc
source /home/user(用户名)/programs/plc-2.0/bin/clik_profile.sh
```

and `source ~/.bashrc`